# Clarification regarding notation: a $\mathbb{C}[X]$ -basis of $\operatorname{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[X]$

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I came across the following sentence in an article:

> The derivations $\frac{\partial}{\partial F_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial F_n}$ form a $\mathbb{C}[X]$-basis of $\operatorname{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[X]$ ...

Here $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is the polynomial algebra in finitely many variables, and $\operatorname{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[X]$ is the vector space (even Lie algebra) over the field $\mathbb{C}$ of derivations of polynomials.

**Question:** What is a $\mathbb{C}[X]$-basis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if R is a ring, an R-basis of an R-module M  is a set B of elements of M such that every element of M can be expressed uniquely as an R-linear combination of elements of B. A module admits an R-basis if and only if it is a free module (indeed, this is the definition of free module!)

In your case the set of derivations is a module for the polynomial ring in the following way: if $d$ is a derivation and $f$ a polynomial then $(f.d)(p) =fd(p)$ for any polynomial $p$.

Comment: So $\operatorname{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[X]$ is both a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of some dimension, and also a free $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module of rank $n$.

Comment: Yes. The dimension as a vector space is infinite.